# Case and Count in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table that stores multiple items for a state and I want to get count for every states according to specific conditions. I wrote this query:

```
SELECT
    State_ID,
    State_Name,
    State_All= CASE WHEN type1=1 AND type2=1 THEN COUNT(Id) END
    State_w= CASE WHEN type1=2 AND type2=1 THEN COUNT(Id) END
    State_s= CASE WHEN type1=2 AND type2=2 THEN COUNT(Id) END
FROM
    tblStates
```

but I get this Error:

```
Column 'State_ID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

When I added `GROUP BY` clause For State_ID,I got above error again for State_Name,and when added State_Name to `GROUP BY` clause ,I got error for State_All,State_w,State_s.

I don't have a column called State_All,State_w,State_s in my table.

How I can get count according to specific conditions without using `CURSORS`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this fix it?

```
SELECT
   State_ID,
   State_Name,
   CASE WHEN type1=1 AND type2=1 THEN COUNT(Id) END AS State_All,
   CASE WHEN type1=2 AND type2=1 THEN COUNT(Id) END AS State_w,
   CASE WHEN type1=2 AND type2=2 THEN COUNT(Id) END AS State_s
FROM
   tblStates
GROUP BY State_ID, State_Name
```

Comment: You've only change how the columns are aliases. OP has already tried GROUP BY

Answer (score 12):

You were on the right path.

You put the condition inside the COUNT like this. COUNT ignores NULLs (which is the implied ELSE in the CASE) so you only count true matches. You need the GROUP BY too.

Your error comes from the use of type1 and type2 outside of the COUNT

```
SELECT
    State_ID,
    State_Name,
    State_All = COUNT(CASE WHEN type1=1 AND type2=1 THEN 1 END), 
    State_w = COUNT(CASE WHEN type1=2 AND type2=1 THEN 1 END), 
    State_s = COUNT(CASE WHEN type1=2 AND type2=2 THEN 1 END)
FROM
    tblStates
GROUP BY
    State_ID, State_Name
```

Comment: Great job he is correct my way would error. Keep in mind what if type1=1 and type2=2 as well :)

Answer (score 3):

You can change **Count** to **SUM** because each record result 1

```
SELECT
    State_ID,
    State_Name,
    State_All = SUM(CASE WHEN type1=1 AND type2=1 THEN 1 END), 
    State_w = SUM(CASE WHEN type1=2 AND type2=1 THEN 1 END), 
    State_s = SUM(CASE WHEN type1=2 AND type2=2 THEN 1 END)
FROM
    tblStates
GROUP BY
    State_ID, State_Name
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add both columns in the end of your query:

```
GROUP BY State_ID, State_Name
```

Comment: I said when I add `GROUP BY State_ID, State_Name` agian I got error for State_All,... .

Comment: It wasn't clear from your question, I thought you meant you tried State_ID and then tried State_Name instead.